# Ruby: iterate and nest hashes on condition

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have two arrays of hashes like this:

```
h1=[{id:1, item:1, from: DateTime.new(2017,9,4,6,0,0,'+0300'), to: DateTime.new(2017,9,4,17,59,59,'+0300'), value:10},
    {id:1, item:2, from: DateTime.new(2017,9,4,18,0,0,'+0300'), to: DateTime.new(2017,9,4,23,59,59,'+0300'), value:10}]

h2=[{id:1, item:1, date: DateTime.new(2017,9,4,6,10,0,'+0300'), value:5},
    {id:2, item:1, date: DateTime.new(2017,9,4,7,20,0,'+0300'), value:7},
    {id:3, item:1, date: DateTime.new(2017,9,4,8,05,0,'+0300'), value:10},
    {id:4, item:1, date: DateTime.new(2017,9,4,18,19,10,'+0300'), value:1},
    {id:5, item:2, date: DateTime.new(2017,9,4,19,20,0,'+0300'), value:2},
    {id:6, item:2, date: DateTime.new(2017,9,4,22,22,0,'+0300'), value:5},
    {id:7, item:2, date: DateTime.new(2017,9,5,23,0,0,'+0300'), value:1}]
```

I need to nest under each `h1` any hash from `h2`, which match criteria:

1. `item` value (e.g., `item:1` in both hashes)
2. `date` from `h2` is in `from` - `to` range in `h1`

So far I can simply nest all hashes under `h1` with this one:

```
my_hash = h1.each do 
  |mh| mh[:inventory]=h2
end
```

I believe criteria matching thing could be done with this:

```
h2.find{ |i| i[:item] == h1[:item] && i[:date].between?(h2[:from], h2[:to]) }
```

**How do I put it together to make it work, please? Thank you!**

**Update 2**

I'm trying to find for each `h1` matched `h2` hashes with this one:

```
my_hash = h1.each do |hsh| 
  h2.each do |hsh2| 
    hash=hsh2.find{|h| h[:item] == hsh[:item] && h[:date].between?(hsh[:from],hsh[:to])} if hash
    hsh[:inventory] = hash
  end 
end
```

however I get error `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) from (pry):12:in "hash"`.
What am I doing wrong here, please?

**Update 3**
If possible ideal output would be something like this:

```
=> [:order=>{:id=>1,
  :item=>1,
  :from=>Mon, 04 Sep 2017 06:00:00 +0300,
  :to=>Mon, 04 Sep 2017 17:59:59 +0300,
  :value=>10,
  :inventory=>
   {:id=>1, :item=>1, :date=>Mon, 04 Sep 2017 06:10:00 +0300, :value=>5},
   {:id=>2, :item=>1, :date=>Mon, 04 Sep 2017 07:20:00 +0300, :value=>7},
   {:id=>3, :item=>1, :date=>Mon, 04 Sep 2017 08:05:00 +0300, :value=>10}
  :order=>{:id=>1,
  :item=>2,
  :from=>Mon, 04 Sep 2017 18:00:00 +0300,
  :to=>Mon, 04 Sep 2017 23:59:59 +0300,
  :value=>10,
  :inventory=>
   {:id=>4, :item=>2, :date=>Mon, 04 Sep 2017 18:19:10 +0300, :value=>1},
   {:id=>5, :item=>2, :date=>Mon, 04 Sep 2017 19:20:00 +0300, :value=>2},
   {:id=>6, :item=>2, :date=>Mon, 04 Sep 2017 22:22:00 +0300, :value=>5},
   {:id=>7, :item=>2, :date=>Mon, 04 Sep 2017 23:00:00 +0300, :value=>1}}]
```

For each `h1` I would like to give new key `order` and then nest appropriate `h2` hashes under `inventory` key.

Comment: Could you add an expected output?

Comment: There is no key `:inventory` in neither of input hashes.

Comment: @SebastiánPalma Please, see my Update 3 above where I added output example + extended my question regarding parent and child hash keys.

Comment: @mudasobwa Please, see my Update 3 above where I cleared my question with output example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works on ruby 2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899) [x64-mingw32]

```
h1.each do |hsh1|
    hsh1[:inventory] =
        h2.find do |hsh2|
            hsh2[:item] == hsh1[:item] &&
            hsh2[:date].between?(hsh1[:from],hsh1[:to])
        end || Hash.new
end
```

You can play around with the default value of hsh1[:inventory] by replacing `Hash.new` with the desired default value.

Comment: Thank you, however it seems to nest only single hash from `h2` under `h1`, not all possible. Could you take a look on my Update 3 above where I added output example and cleared my question, please?

Comment: Silly me, I can substitute `find` with `find_all` and then it will nest all hashes matching my criteria :)